# Running "go doc" results in "no such tool" error

Tags: go, godoc

I've run into a very strange issue, and even though I'm sure the solution is simple, but I can't find anything online about this.  Trying to use `go doc <args...>` for any set of arguments always results in the error:

`go tool: no such tool "doc"`

despite `doc` showing up in the command output for `go help` and `go help doc` providing documentation of and usage for `go doc`.

What's going on here?  I even tried downloading the tar.gz bundle from golang.org because I figured maybe the version I installed with `pacman` was bad, but the unzipped `go` also had the same issue (with, of course, a properly altered `GOPATH`).

Comment: "Trying to use go doc <args...> for any set of arguments" You could be doing anything! Give specific examples. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code [command] working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code [command] necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Remove all your Go installations and install as described from golang.org.

Comment: Can you find the "$GOROOT/bin/godoc" bin file? Try to run "which godoc". The command "go doc" is actually calling the "godoc" I believe, some package manager just not install them fully, or forget to set some more ENV var.

Comment: @nvcnvn The command "go doc" runs the command "doc" in the tool exec dir, not the "godoc" command.

Comment: I use go on arch linux and have never had this problem. I suspect something in your environment is messed up.

Comment: @peterSO `go doc` doesn't work, that's the minimum example.  The command I was trying to run is `go doc "regex/syntax"`, but regardless of the parameters I pass to `go doc`, I get the same error, which is why I did not provide any specific usage.

Comment: @Volker As I mentioned in the question, grabbing the gz file with the preinstalled binaries from golang.org and setting $GOPATH to point to its unzipped location (which is, in effect, their recommended installation method) resulted in the same error.

Comment: @peterSO I made a typo, but it should be "regexp/syntax," as stated by this page: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that my system version of go was gccgo v1.10.3 - installing go v1.11.4 resolved the issue.